# ogr SetAttributeFilter uppercase?

Tags: ogr, select-by-attribute

How do I use the ogr `SetAttributeFilter` with uppercases?

Code example:

```
lyr = shp_obj.GetLayer()
sel_str = "%s = '%s'" % (field, value)
lyr.SetAttributeFilter(sel_str)
```

Can I just do:

```
 sel_str = "UPPER(%s) = '%s'" % (field, value)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to according to the [OGR SQL reference](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_sql.html).

> WHERE Limitations
>      ...
>      All string comparisons are case insensitive except for <, >, <= and >=

Comment: I must have overseen this when I looked at the reference. Thanks mate.